# regex for oracle "create procedure" definition

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regex-lookarounds

I need regex to capture full "create procedure" statement.

Here is one of examples, which I used for testing my regex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_for_comp (P_VARNAME IN VARCHAR2, P_VALUE IN OUT NUMBER)
   as
   v_if_exists NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN
   SELECT   COUNT(*) INTO v_if_exists FROM PKG_VAR WHERE VARIABLENAME = P_VARNAME;
   IF v_if_exists > 0
   THEN
      begin
         SELECT VALUE INTO P_VALUE FROM PKG_VAR WHERE VARIABLENAME = P_VARNAME;
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
      end;
ELSE
      begin
         INSERT INTO PKG_VAR  VALUES(P_VARNAME, P_VALUE);
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
      end;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Current regex:

```
/CREATE\s+(OR\s+REPLACE\s+)?PROCEDURE\s+(\w+)\s*\(((?!.*\bEND\b\s*(\w+\s*)?\;\s*\/).*\s*)+.+/
```

As for my issue: I use QRegularExpression class and program failed when I run it on large files. Also, when I run it on small file - all works correctly.

After a lot of tests on online debuggers, like regexr.com, I could not find problem in regex.

How I should change it and where are may be problems?

Comment: regex might be a good tool to find things, but parsing complex code, whether it should be `html`, `sql` or whatever , shouldn´t be done with it.
What would happen if you define a method inside the declartion aswell, you would need to rewrite the whole regex and it would be unreadable quite fast, aswell as it wouldn´t be maintainable and it could lead to several "bugs".

Comment: Try [`CREATE\s+(OR\s+REPLACE\s+)?PROCEDURE\s+(\w+)\s*\([^\n]+(?:\n(?!END;\n)[^\n]*)*\nEND;`](https://regex101.com/r/tV8bW4/1). It is based on the unroll the loop technique and should be much more efficient. Note that your tempered regex token is broken since you check for `.*` inside the lookahead part. If it works, I will post with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Try something very simple like:

```
CREATE(\s+OR\s+REPLACE)\s+PROCEDURE.*?END;\s*/
```

It just looks for the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` at the start and then the end will be `END;` followed by `/` (indicating the end of the PL/SQL block in the SQL scope) on the next line with the minimal amount between.

*(Note: You will probably want to use the `ni` regular expression match parameters to allow `.` to match the newline character and to do case-insensitive matches.)*

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE script (value ) AS
SELECT  'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_for_comp (P_VARNAME IN VARCHAR2, P_VALUE IN OUT NUMBER)' || CHR(10)
        || '   as' || CHR(10)
        || '   v_if_exists NUMBER(10,0);' || CHR(10)
        || 'BEGIN' || CHR(10)
        || '   SELECT   COUNT(*) INTO v_if_exists FROM PKG_VAR WHERE VARIABLENAME = P_VARNAME;' || CHR(10)
        || '   IF v_if_exists > 0' || CHR(10)
        || '   THEN' || CHR(10)
        || '      begin' || CHR(10)
        || '         SELECT VALUE INTO P_VALUE FROM PKG_VAR WHERE VARIABLENAME = P_VARNAME;' || CHR(10)
        || '         EXCEPTION' || CHR(10)
        || '         WHEN OTHERS THEN' || CHR(10)
        || '            NULL;' || CHR(10)
        || '      end;' || CHR(10)
        || 'ELSE' || CHR(10)
        || '      begin' || CHR(10)
        || '         INSERT INTO PKG_VAR  VALUES(P_VARNAME, P_VALUE);' || CHR(10)
        || '         EXCEPTION' || CHR(10)
        || '         WHEN OTHERS THEN' || CHR(10)
        || '            NULL;' || CHR(10)
        || '      end;' || CHR(10)
        || '   END IF;' || CHR(10)
        || 'END;' || CHR(10)
        || '/'
FROM DUAL;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   script
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( value, '^CREATE(\s+OR\s+REPLACE)\s+PROCEDURE.*?END;\s*/$', 'n' );
```

**Outputs**:

```
COUNT(*)
--------
       1
```